# Convert range of column titles to variables for vars() function

Tags: r, dataframe, variables

I have a data frame with 100+ variables listed in columns, and each subject in rows. I'd like to loop through each column to perform an ANOVA, and while the loop function works fine the step I am stuck on is listing which columns to loop through. Currently I can set these by manually typing/pasting each variable name but this is obviously not practical.

Currently the loop runs through my list of `vars`, to get this I currently just type the name of these columns manually...

```r
variables <- vars(height, width, strength)
```

Which only loops for those selected 3 out of 100+ variables that I have had to manually type in.

I had thought I could list the range of column names for dataframe `df` between columns 3 to 100 within the `vars` expression as below...

```r
variables <- vars(colnames(df[3:100]))
```

This just provides one variable of the name `colnames(df[3:100])`.

Any ideas to avoid typing or manually inserting commas/removing quotation marks from 100+ different variable names? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69094831/how-to-perform-nested-anova-by-groups-using-r/69095196#69095196

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider [**`do.call`**](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/do.call) which is shorthand for expanded list of arguments to a function. Specifically, below:

```r
variables <- do.call(vars, colnames(df)[3:100])
```

is equivalent to expanded version:

```r
variables <- vars(colnames(df)[3], colnames(df)[4], ..., colnames(df)[100])
```